# Relation between a maximal ideal and an invertible ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, integral-domain

Let $D$ be a domain, $\mathfrak{a,b,p}\subsetneq D$ ideals with $\mathfrak{p}$ maximal and $\mathfrak{a}$ invertible (there is some $\mathfrak{c}$ ideal with $\mathfrak{ac}=\mu D$, with $\mu\in D\setminus\{0\}$).

> If $\mathfrak{ap\subseteq b\subseteq a}$ then $\mathfrak{b=ap \;\vee \; b=a}$.

I've been working for a hour on this but don't get nothing right. Please some hint or help.

Comment: I through that every prime ideal is maximal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but $\mathfrak p\subseteq\mathfrak b\mathfrak a^{-1}\subseteq D$ gives immediately what you want.

Comment: Why algebra is so injust! :( your answer is right. Since $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal

Comment: I don't think the answer is that easy, since $\mathfrak a\cdot \mathfrak a^{-1}$ could be not contained in $D$. The ideal $\mathfrak a^{-1}$ is a fractional ideal in general so you can't use maximality of $\mathfrak p$ to deduce the claim from $\mathfrak p\subseteq \mathfrak a^{-1}\mathfrak b$.

Comment: @Ferra AFAIK a fractional ideal $I$ is invertible if there is a fractional ideal $J$ such that $IJ=D$. (Btw, if one defines $I^{-1}$ as $(D:_KI)$, then *always* $II^{-1}\subseteq D$.)

Comment: ah you're right, the fact that $\mathfrak b\subseteq \mathfrak a $ implies that $\mathfrak b\mathfrak a^{-1}\subseteq D$. Then I agree with you!

Comment: In this case, $\mathfrak{a}^{-1}=\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: @LuisFelipe From your definition I think $\mathfrak a^{-1}=\mu^{-1}\mathfrak c$.

Comment: Ah you're right. I'm typing in the bus and i forget $\mu^{-1}$